# How to change Bitcoin core 25.0 configuration?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf

I installed Bitcoin Core 25.0. Synchronization finished after a few days. Unfortunately, I made a big mistake, I configured the files incorrectly and now the application does not open.
I must honestly admit that this whole configuration is black magic to me.
I have a problem adding the screenshot, so I am copying the text that appears when I try to open `bicoin-tx.exe`.

> "Error: Invalid combination of -regtest, -signet, -testnet and -chain. Can use at most one."

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are providing more than one network specifier across your starting command and your configuration file. Make sure that you only specify the single network (Bitcoin, testnet, signet, or regtest) that you want your node to connect to. If that network does not match the one that you previously synchronized for, your node will have synchronize again, since each of these networks has its own blockchain history. If you don’t provide any network, your node will synchronize with the Bitcoin network.

Comment: I accidentally added "regtest, signet and tesnet" ..... how can I correct it now?

Comment: If you added the lines to the `bitcoin.conf`, you can open that file again, remove those lines, save, and exit. If you added these additional configurations to your startup options, you can edit the startup command to remove them. If you want more specific instructions, please share what your configuration file and/or startup command look like

Comment: I would like to share the bitcoin.conf file so you can see it clearly, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Fix: I added all these files to bitcoin-qt.exe